# Как добавть расширение из google store в electron (nightmare)

Tags: node.js, chrome-extension, electron, nightmare.js

Есть сайт, на который невозможно зайти без установленного в браузер расширения. На хромиум ставится просто копированием файлов из хрома и работает. Мне нужно зайти на сайт с помощью nightmare. В оф. документации ничего не нашел. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: плз, напишите причину по которой вы используете nightmare

Comment: Автоматизация рутинного процесса на корпоративном портале

Comment: это уже готовый продукт или вы начинаете разрабатывать новый?

Comment: Продукт готовый. API нет.

Comment: если вам нужно использовать именно nightmare то прийдётся много исследовать. в этом, довольно старом, продукте используется electron версии 2 в котором был метод `BrowserWindow.addExtension(path)`. читайте исходники и ищите способ прокинуть в nightmare путь к файлам расширения

Comment: Спасибо. А если не именно nightmare, то про какой продукт идёт речь?

Comment: Puppeteer, https://pptr.dev/